# Google Maps API Distance Matrix - Delay time to request (client-side) another 100 elements

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I have a mini-map project that uses Distance Matrix Google Maps API to create a polyline (route) from start point to end point. I have many markers in my map and I have to connect them using Distance Matrix API to fetch the duration value.

The problem is the total requests of the Distance Matrix API are more than 100 elements, exactly 400 elements. I know that Google Maps API limit only to 100 elements per client-side request. According to the documentation,

> While you are no longer limited to a maximum number of elements per
>   day (EPD), the following usage limits are still in place for the
>   Distance Matrix API:
>
> Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request. Maximum 100
>   elements per server-side request. Maximum 100 elements per client-side
>   request. 1000 elements per second (EPS), calculated as the sum of
>   client-side and server-side queries.

So, I decide to divide the 400 elements into 4 requests (100 elements each). **However, the documentation doesn't state how long should I wait to request another 100 elements.**

Does anyone know?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#UsageLimits) does say how long you should wait here:

> Note: The rate limit is applied per user session, regardless of how
>   many users share the same project. When you first load the API, you
>   are allocated an initial quota of elements. Once you use this quota,
>   the API enforces rate limits on additional requests on a per-second
>   basis. If too many requests are made within a certain time period, the
>   API returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code.

So you'll need to wait at least 1 second before you make another request to the Distance Matrix client-side service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Maximum 100 elements per server-side request."
what does it mean by elements? I understand origins and destinations. But elements?